# Is it possible to limit the "sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing" role?

Tags: editor-user-permissions

Is it possible to limit the *sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing* role?

Our client has a team that manages security accounts on their site and they are requesting a "limited" *sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing* role that would limit the user to managing roles only (i.e. not access rights), and if possible only certain roles.

If this isn't possible, we can create a custom admin tool for this. I'd just rather support the built in GUIs than my own, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by changing the security on the application in the core database. The Role Manager located here: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Security/Role Manager`. The default security on it has `/sitecore/content/Applications/Security/Role Manager` with read permission:

[image]

You could add a new role that only has read permissions for this application and not any of the other security applications, or you could remove read access from the `Sitecore Client Account Managing` role.

As for only managing certain roles, that would have to be done via a custom application, there is nothing out of the box that will do that AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking for the application too.